# Unknown (Obsolete?) Capacitor Markings Green Caps

Tags: capacitor, identification

I am in the process of replacing cracked and leaking capacitors in an old 1970s Johnson Viking 4740 transceiver. What I thought would be a simple swap wasn't.

The modern version of these capacitors have markings that don't relate to the ones I have pulled. I have searched all over the internet and can find nothing resembling my problem. There must be others with this problem, or will be in the future.

Can anyone "translate" these for me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Yes, those look a bit old and worn out.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. These are old mylar capacitors before a unified coding system was implemented. But the codes are easy to read, as during this period in history the nF was the point of reference unless xxpF was used to imply that this value was in pF. 0.03K meant 30nF. 0.15K was 150nF. 0.01 is 10 nF, etc

They look a little aged in the photo. You might consider replacing them with new ones.

Electrolytic capacitors had and still have the actual values on them, including a temperature spec such as 150C.

This is a photo of an old style mylar capacitor. 100.77 nF 100 volt.

[image]

Comment: They all appear to be 10% tolerance and rated 50 volts.

Comment: Would the .1K then be 100nf and what are the 2 zeroes for, in the 005 50?

Comment: "during this period in history" ... we didn't use nF.  So, all those markings are in uF.  The K is something like a temperature coefficient.  The 50 means 50 volts, typical for this type of capacitor.

Comment: @AlmostDone. You are likely correct.

Comment: @Johnno. 005 is 5 nF and 50 volts. The ink is worn off of some of these, but body size coincides with capacitive value, if these are all 50 volt rated.

Comment: @gbarry. I am old enough to remember using these as off the shelf parts in the 70's. A point followed by a sensible value was always in nF. The 'K' was the scale used(x1,000pF, so it was a nF scale), and it never changed in that era. Much has changed since then. That same package size today would be rated 100 volt. Some of them may still have their original value.

Comment: Does the voltage rating matter? I am looking at some Nichicon polyester types. For example: Nichicon 10nF Polyester Capacitor PET 250 V ac, 630 V dc ±10% or should I try to get closer to the original voltage value?

Comment: Size is usually the driving issue, as in available space. A 50 volt cap is still ok to use, and would be much smaller than 1970's style.

Comment: Most plastic caps will have the properties need for that radio. Ceramic is microphonic. Plastic is low leakage.  PE,PU,Polystyrene, Teflon will all work. So PE you chose is ok. The tolerances are poor in plastic, so they are not in critical areas. So 10% is good. Voltage doesn't matter if rated much more as long as it fits.

Comment: 0.0047uF 100V 4mm Greencap Capacitor or 0.0056uF 100V 4mm Greencap Capacitor, will either of those suffice for the 005 marked capacitor in the posted photo? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Yes, considering the loose tolerance of the 1970's.

Comment: @Sparky256 Amazing if you're right; it means I grew up never knowing--and it never mattered!  But I remember mf and mmf (for uF and pF), and I don't recall ever seeing "nF" on any schematic...?

Comment: nF may be common on a schematic, but not on a cap.